# Handle tab correctly when counting location information in Lex?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I have read the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Tracking-Locations.html#Tracking-Locations) about how to track location information, but still have problem. It seems that Lex (2.5) counts both space and tab as one character, and that makes the error reporting with wrong column number. Currently, I have the editor to replace tab with spaces for the parser. But I wonder if there is a way to handle tab correctly in Lex itself.

Comment: How many spaces equal one tab? 2? 4? 8?  This is a personal preference.  You'd have to build a configurable option into your lex-generated program to account for this preference.  It doesn't seem to me that it's worth the trouble.

Comment: In my case, the tab should be equal to 4 spaces. I tried to modify [YY_USER_ACTION](http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596155971/error-]reporting-recovery.html), but without any luck. The column number always wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unputc` to perform dirty trickery with the input stream. When you match a tab use `unputc` to put four spaces in the input steam...

Manual extract:

> unput(c) puts the character c back onto the input stream. It will be
>   the next character scanned. The following action will take the current
>   token and cause it to be rescanned enclosed in parentheses.
>
> ```
> {
> int i;
> /* Copy yytext because unput() trashes yytext */
> char *yycopy = strdup( yytext );
> unput( ')' );
> for ( i = yyleng - 1; i >= 0; --i )
>     unput( yycopy[i] );
> unput( '(' );
> free( yycopy );
> }
> ```
>
> Note that since each unput() puts the given character back at the beginning of the input stream, pushing back strings must be done
>   back-to-front.